# spans from ordered dates with PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
group | date
a     | 2002-01-03
a     | 2002-01-17
a     | 2002-03-18
b     | 2001-01-02
```

I'd like to turn this into a series of spans like

```
group | start      | stop
a     | 2002-01-03 | 2002-01-17
a     | 2002-01-17 | 2002-03-18
a     | 2002-03-18 |
b     | 2001-01-02 |
```

I could do this with

```sql
select distinct on (left.group, left.date) 
    left.group as group,
    left.date as start,
    right.date as stop
from dates as left
left join dates as right
on left.group = right.group
    and left.date < right.date
order by group, left.date, right.date
```

but is there a better way to do this (the large join and sorting are slow on the real table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select d.*, lead(d.date) over (partition by d.group order by date)
from dates d
order by group, start;
```

Comment: does this need to be "select d.*, lead(d.date) over (partition by d.group order by date)
from dates d order by d.date" or is that outer "order by" not necessary?

Comment: @fgregg The outer "order by" is unnecessary because it's handled in the `OVER()` clause. Window functions run after the dataset is realized.

Comment: @fgregg . . . If you want the results in a particular order, then you should always include an `order by` in the outermost query.  Ignore what JSpratt has commented.  That is simply wrong.